# Move whole row based on column A to offset(-1,4)

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a large Excel file where the data doesn't line up with the corresponding headers.

In order to fix this I need to cut and paste all of the rows where column "A" contains "Planned" up one row and four columns to the right. I have a few thousand rows that need to be moved (with VBA). I have been working on piecing together some code but with no avail (I have limited knowledge of VBA).

The below shows a snapshot of the data I am working with. I need the yellow row to be moved to the red area. The green row on top is an example of what it looks like after manually making the change. Hopefully this code would loop through the whole sheet give me data that lines up with their respectful headers.

(the row of yellow data that needs to be moved is 60 columns wide by the way, the picture only shows a small snapshot of the worksheet)

[image]

Comment: Looks like you had a line feed in your import data. Are you correcting the data feed for the future?

Comment: If you have truly been *'working on piecing together some code ...'* then I suggest you post some or all of the code (working or not) in order that we can gauge any unanswered questions we may have.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty, untested solution. Give it a go.

```
Dim cel as range
For each cel in Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").end(xldown).row
    if cel.value = "Planned:" then
        cel.resize(1,60).cut
        cel.offset(-1,4).pastespecial xlpasteall
    end if
next cel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method (without VBA)

1. select the destination region (red region)
2. hit `Ctrl+g` then click the `Special` button
3. choose `Blank`, click `Ok`

   [image]
4. type in the reference formula (e.g. in `E3` the formula be `=A4`) and hit `Ctrl+Enter` to fill all
5. copy paste the entire red column as value (i.e. remove the formula)
6. filter column A for value `Planned:` and delete the rows.

I know this has a drawback, on step 6 if your data is VERY LARGE, Excel might fail to delete filtered rows properly

Answer (score 0):

This short procedure should take care of the aberrant import data while shifting the now-empty 'planned' lines up.

```
Sub fix_planned()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If LCase(Left(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, 8)) = "planned:" Then
                .Range(.Cells(rw, 1), .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy _
                  Destination:=.Cells(rw, 1).Offset(-1, 4)
                .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Suggest you fix the source of the data so you do not have to repeatedly repair the data 'after-the-fact'.